# jQuery Smooth Scrolling Alignment

Tags: jquery, html, css

On my [this section of my GitHub page](http://panchr.github.io/#repositories), my smooth scrolling method does not align the navigation with the border of the last section.

Using the up-arrow at the bottom-right of the screen, the orange border of the navigation header lines up exactly with the orange border of the `#about` div. However, this does not line up with the `#languages` div's border for some reason. If I remove the slider (`#repositories-slider`), it lines up correctly. Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page hasn't enough height at the last `div.container` so it cannot reach the `#repositories-test` at the right height. Adding some more height to your last `div.container` made it line out right for me.

```
<div class="container full-page-section" id="repositories-test" style="height: 626px;">
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually had to do this (incrementing the last divider's height by 1) because the height is dynamic based on screen size, but this still solved my problem :)